# Error 404 el usar @Query en Spring

Tags: spring, sql

Me arroja error 404 cuando creo este método. El método no se esta ejecutando. No tengo como identificar el error.

He colocado inclusive consultas básicas como un `select * from Publicaciones` y me da el mismo resultado.

```
@Query("select h from Publicaciones h where h.titulo = :titulo")    
public List<Publicacion> findByTitulo(@Param("titulo") String titulo);
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio para entender como funcionamos aquí y de paso ganar tu primera medalla, a su vez, te recomiendo pasar por [ask] para ver como elaborar una buena pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida, por favor, considera también invertir algo de tu tiempo en realizar un [mcve] , tal y como está la pregunta falta información para poder reproducir el problema, considera editarla para que podamos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: y donde esta el return de ese metodo?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Es una interfaz, el método no tienes que escribirlo realmente, es generado por Spring en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: ah si eso veo, es que es 404 indica que no encuentra el recurso a lo mejor en la implementacion de la interfaz no retorna a la pagina que necesita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta el atributo value delante de la query

```
@Query(value = "select h from Publicaciones h where h.titulo = :titulo")    
public List<Publicacion> findByTitulo(@Param("titulo") String titulo);
```

Comment: Eso faltaba, ademas es Publicacion, y no Publicaciones, ya que SpringJPA trabaja directamente con el modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado tu pregunta es incompleta. Pero creo que puedo ayudarte, este código de ejemplo puede ayudarte a resolver el problema.

```
 @Query(value = "select h from Publicaciones h where h.titulo = ?1")
   public List<Publicacion> findByTitulo(String titulo);
```

Comment: Si el error es HTTP Status 404, no tiene nada que ver con el código que OP ha escrito

Comment: Depende, si el error se lanza al no encontrar un objeto en bbdd si tiene que ver. Por ejemplo con el código de OP puede que al estar mal escrito no encuentre ningún objeto, por lo que lanza incorrectamente 404. De todas formas la información esta incompleta como comente

Comment: @Alber en ese caso daria un error NPE

Comment: No si se controla, he visto muchos caso del tipo if null then throw NotFoundException